# CSS - Make nice slider without putting image in HTML

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make something like this:

http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_6719449301396601413.jpg

The problem is i am totaly new in CSS and i have no idea how to make it, i just try something like:

```
.newsnames{
    background-image: url("images/newsname-right.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width:572px;
    height:227px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute; left: 415px; top: 39px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 13px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 45px;    
}
```

But it just giving it that dark background and position , but what i need is to let everything looks like on image and i am completly lost, can somebody help me with it?

My actualy try can be see here: http://funedit.com/andurit/newnew/

p.s. Its really important that all image have to go to CSS not to HTML!

Shuld i divide it for 3 parts? (that blue arrow, mid, and right with date and chat buble? If yea how can i change 3 things with one a:hover?

Comment: please create a jsfiddle where we can do some fancy stuff and edit the link to your question then. http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yeah I'd like to see it on jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JEzdF/2/ here it is but without images some parts looks terrible :(

Answer (score 0):

you have to give z-index to your css so that the layer to your right will show on top of your image

```
    .newsnames{
        background-image: url("images/newsname-right.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        width:572px;
        height:227px;
        display:inline-block;
        position: absolute; left: 415px; top: 39px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-weight: 13px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 45px;    
        z-index: 1000;
}
```

what happens is your image is projected outward in the z plane so it appears on top of your background image.

you can provide your other elements inside this div itself ...

Comment: my background image is showing fine :) jus becuase on fiddle its not uploaded any image its not showing :(

Answer (score 0):

> Shuld i divide it for 3 parts? (that blue arrow, mid, and right with date and chat buble? If yea how can i change 3 things with one a:hover?

In my opinion your only chance is to use jquery to realize this demand (especially the last part).